# Should we build an interaction patterns library on UX Stackexchange?

Tags: discussion

With the inclusion of Balsamiq Mockups we would have a great tool to build an interaction patterns library. Should we start one?

I would really like to have one, that can be easily extended. A lot of the current libraries feel to static to me and often don't have the right granularity. It would be awesome to have common problems and find different solutions to it. 
This way, lots of questions could be answered by referring to the right interaction patterns.

We could then start to create a new tag interaction-pattern. Make it a community wiki, where one could post examples. Answers could be alternatives or better implementations of the mentioned pattern.

Answer (score 6):

We're a Q&A site, not a pattern repository.

I think an interesting side effect of answering questions might be that at some point we may well effectively contain many useful patterns and someone could go ahead and create a summary of all that information, but I don't see the point in going and misusing the question and tagging system to achieve that artificially.

If you want to create an interesting interaction pattern library, why don't you go ahead? The content of our Q&A is available in a Creative Commons license, so you can use that material to get started.

Comment: Once the body of content has developed sufficiently to be able to _have_ a sufficient number of examples of various patterns, it would make sense for such content lists to live in tag-wikis.

Answer (score 3):

Some good discussion on this topic was already had on [this meta post](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/768/should-we-allow-community-wiki-type-lists-posts-on-the-main-site).

We're a Q&A site, not a pattern library. Even ignoring the scope of the site (it's for answerable, not discussable, topics) the site is simply not designed to be a pattern library. We don't have browsable sections, we have tags. We don't have an image focused presentation, we have a problem focused presentation.

Adding pattern libraries on UX.SE is at best fitting a square peg into a round hole; as a UX community we owe it to our users and ourselves to keep pattern libraries on sites *designed* to be pattern libraries.